# How to get from Europe to Boston by ship with 2 kids?

Tags: boston

I would like to make trip transatlantic from Europe (France, UK) to Boston with two kids in July 2019. Could you advice how to do it affordable, safe and entertaining? Thank you

Comment: You book a cruise. Southampton-Boston is a decently popular route. Cost $750 ish a person last time I looked. Talk to a travel agent or look at a site like Expedia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any transatlantic cruises between Québec and London, England?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113982/are-there-any-transatlantic-cruises-between-qu%c3%a9bec-and-london-england)

Comment: Cruise in July 2019 and "affordable" are not very compatible, since July is high season. There isn't a lot of stuff in the North Atlantic, so you need to plan for a lot of "at sea" days. Fastest is probably Cunard: Southampton to New York which does it in 7 days with no stops whatsoever. I'd consider  including New York in the search, since it's a fairly inexpensive 4 hour bus ride to get from NY to Boston and NY has way more service